# Вывод чисел , формула с полями ввода (калькулятор ) php

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте , интересует такой вопрос...у меня сейчас кнопочки такого плана

```
 <input type="radio" name="task" value="a" />
```

и три кнопочки такого

```
 <input type="radio" name="aukcion" value="two" />
```

Вывод оформлен таким вот образом, задействованы только с именем aukcion

```
 $task = $_POST['aukcion'];
if ($task == 'two') {
$result = $res * $auk2;
}
elseif ($task == 'eight') {
$result = $res * $auk8;
}
else {
$result = $res * $auk24;
}
echo 'Налог на товар: ' .   $result  . ' <br /> ';
```

Каким мне образом сделать , к примеру если нажали кнопочку

> value="a"

которая не задействована , стоит для красоты, то вывод данных шел или совсем иначе , либо к результату добавлялась еще одна переменная к примеру

> $head

Comment: Несколько вопросов лучше разбивать на несколько разных тем - так их потом проще искать и проще дать более полный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом, проверить определено ли значение task и равно ли оно строке 'a'. В случае совпадения обоих условий, добавить к результату значение переменной $head.

```
$task = $_POST['aukcion'];
if ($task == 'two') {
  $result = $res * $auk2;
} elseif ($task == 'eight') {
  $result = $res * $auk8;
} else {
  $result = $res * $auk24;
}
if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'a') $result += $head;
echo 'Налог на товар: ' .   $result  . ' <br /> ';
```

Возможно поле task вам будет удобнее сделать флажком, а не радио-кнопкой, раз оно одно

```
<input type="checkbox" name="task" value="a" />
```

Comment: Извините , но мне не нужно понимать )) мне нужно добавить в код `$task = $_POST['aukcion'];` как бы если нажали `value="two"` и нажали `value="a"` одновремененно то к результату еще будет добавлятся число  `$result = $res * $auk2 + $head;`

Comment: Поспешил дать ответ, это не совсем то, что было вам нужно. Переработал решение в более корректный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо )) утром попробую)

Comment: Спасибо ) а как решить проблемы с цифрами не поможете ?

Comment: Лучше отдельным вопросом - так вы сможете собрать больше решений, когда посетители видят множество вопросов в одном - они часто закрывают тему. Да и сама структура сайта не поощряет обсуждение множества разных вопросов в одной теме. Но вообще у вас подход верный - надо сначала перевести число в строку, с ней уже гораздо удобнее работать.

Comment: я изменил этот вопрос ) я перерыл пол интернета и не могу найти решения

Comment: Лучше бы новый вопрос задали, вы изменяете вопрос - ответ становится бессмысленным. Если кто-то находит его и пытается использовать - вы его дезориентируете. Он видит вопрос и принятый ответ, который совершенно не соответствует вопросу.

Comment: Кроме того, в вопрос, который уже отмечен как решенный, заглянет на порядок меньше отвечающих, разве что только случайно, поэтому, если у вас возникает проблема, лучше задавать во-первых новый вопрос, во-вторых в одной теме размещать только один вопрос.

Comment: изменил вопрос по ответу. вернул другую часть ) спасибо...